# Why does pasting(ctrl-v) sometimes break merged cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste, font-size

I am creating a PO form for my department.  I have 2 cells merged with text wrap for the item description.  If I copy a product name from Amazon and paste it into these merged cells, the merge breaks and text does not wrap.  If I take the same text and paste into google search bar and then recopy the text and paste into the merged cells everything functions as normal.  It does not appear to be the length of text but rather the font size that is the issue. Paste special- values only also fixes the problem but I am trying to make this form usable without special instructions. Does anyone have a work around or at least confirm font size can break a cell merge?

Answer (score 0):

Font size is not relevant. You're copying a special character (likely a newline) at the end of the product name, which causes the merged cells to split.

There isn't anything you can do on your side to fix this, copy pasting formatted text directly from a webpage into your sheet will lead to things breaking.

A few options:

1. Double click on the merged cell, then paste the text into it
2. Select the merged cell and paste the values into the formula bar
3. Paste Special - Values

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*I can confirm this does happen.*

#### Workaround:

Instead of merging cells like this:

[image]

You can just use one cell and expand its width:

[image]

#### Fixing Font Size:

The only issue here is that if you paste in some text which is font size 18 and Times New Roman, if you don't use the `Right Click > Paste Special > Paste values only` then the text decoration will persist. You can fix this with a little script which changes the font to normal on edit:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.setFontSize(10)
    .setFontWeight("normal")
    .setFontFamily("Arial")
    .setFontColor("black")
}
```

This you will need to paste into the script editor for your sheet, by following the `Tools > Script editor` menu item. Once pasted, you will need to save the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Anything pasted will now automatically be converted to Arial, size 10, black, normal weight font:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the layout of the form will not allow me to adjust the size of a single cell. But I will put that script to use.  I appreciate your time.